# Incremental appending: How to avoid performance penalty of struct arrays

Tags: matlab

If you must incrementally append data to arrays, it seems that using individual vectors of basic data types is orders of magnitude faster than an array of structs (with one vector element per record).  Even trying to collect the individual vectors into a struct seems to double the time.  The tests are:

```
N=5e4;

fprintf('\nstruct array (array of structs):\n')
clear x y;
y=struct( 'a',[], 'b',[], 'c',[], 'd',[] );
tic
for iIns = 1 : N
   x.a=rand; x.b=rand; x.c=rand; x.d=rand;
   y(end+1)=x;
end % for iIns
toc

fprintf('\nSeparate arrays of scalars:\n')
clear a b c d;
a=[]; b=[]; c=[]; d=[];
tic
for iIns = 1 : N
   a(end+1) = rand;
   b(end+1) = rand;
   c(end+1) = rand;
   d(end+1) = rand;
end % for iIns
toc

fprintf('\nA struct with arrays of scalars for fields:\n')
clear a b c d x y
x.a=[]; x.b=[]; x.c=[]; x.d=[];
tic
for iIns = 1:N
   x.a(end+1)=rand;
   x.b(end+1)=rand;
   x.c(end+1)=rand;
   x.d(end+1)=rand;
end % for iIns
toc
```

The results:

```
struct array (array of structs):
Elapsed time is 24.127274 seconds.

Separate arrays of scalars:
Elapsed time is 0.048190 seconds.

A struct with arrays of scalars for fields:
Elapsed time is 0.084624 seconds.
```

Even though collecting individual vectors of basic data types into a struct (3rd scenario above) imposes such a penalty, it may be preferrable to simply using individual vectors (second scenario above) because the variables are more organized.  Your variable name space isn't filled up with so many variables which are in fact conceptually grouped.

That's quite a significant penalty, however, to pay for such organization.  I don't suppose there is way to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways to avoid this performance penalty: (1) pre-allocate, and (2) rethink your stance on "organizing" variables. I suggest both. Oh, and if you can, don't use arrays of structs where each field only uses scalars - if your application suddenly has to handle a couple of orders of magnitude more data, the memory overhead will force you to rewrite everything.

**Pre-allocation**

You often know how many elements your array will end up having. Thus, initialize your arrays as `s = struct('a',NaN(1:N),'b',NaN(1:N));` If you don't know ahead of time how many entries there will be, but you can estimate an upper limit, initialize with the upper limit, and either remove the elements, or use functions (e.g. `nanmean`) that do not care if the array has a few extra `NaN`s in the end. If you truly know nothing about the final size (except that `N` will be large enough to matter), pre-allocate with a nice number (e.g. `N=1337`), and extend the array in chunks. MathWorks have sped up dynamic growing of numeric arrays in a recent release, but as you demonstrate in your answer, the optimization has not been applied to structs yet. Don't count MathWorks' optimization team to fix your code.

**Nice variables**

Why worry about your variable space? As long as you use `explicitVariableNames`, your code remains readable and you will have an easy time picking out the right variable. But ok, let's say you want to clean up: The first way to keeping the number of active variables low is to use `clear` or `keep` at strategic points in your code to make sure you only keep around what's needed. The second (assuming you want to optimize for performance), is to put contextually linked vectors into the same array: `objectDimensions = [lengthOfObject, widthOfObject, heightOfObject]`. This keeps everything as numeric arrays (which are fastest), and allows easy vectorization such as `objectVolume = prod(objectDimensions,2);`.

/aside: I should disclose that I used to use structures frequently for assembling results (so that I could return a lot of information a single variable and have the field names be part of the documentation). I have since switched to use object-oriented-programming (usually `handle`-objects), which no only collect related variables, but also the associated functionality, and which facilitate code re-use. I do take a performance hit, but the time it saves me coding makes more than up for it. Note that I do pre-allocate if at all possible (and if it's not just growing an array three times).

---

**Example**

Assume you have a function `getDimensions` that reads dimensions (length, height, width) of objects. However, sometimes, the object is 2D, sometimes it is 3D. Thus, you want to fill the following variables: twoD.length, twoD.width, threeD.length, threeD.width, threeD.height, ideally as arrays of structs, so that each element of a struct corresponds to an object. You do not know ahead of time how many objects there are, all you can do is poll the function `thereAreMoreObjects`, which returns true or false, until there are no more objects.

Here's how you can do this with reasonable efficiency and growing arrays by chunks:

```
%// preassign the temporary variable, and some others
chunkSize = 1000;
numObjects = 0;
idAndDimensions = zeros(chunkSize,4);

while thereAreMoreObjects()
    objectId = getCurrentObjectId();
    %// hi==-1 if it's flat
    [len,wid,hi] = getObjectDimensions(objectId);

    %// allocate more, if needed
    numObjects = numObjects + 1;
    if numObjects > size(idAndDimensions,1)
       %// grow array
       idAndDimensions(end+chunkSize,1) = 0;
    end

    idAndDimensions(numObjects,:) = [objectId, len, wid, hi];
end

%// throw away excess
idAndDimensions = idAndDimensions(1:numObjects,:);

%// split into 2D and 3D objects
isTwoD = numObjects(:,end) == -1;

%// assign twoD struct
twoD = struct('id',num2cell(idAndDimensions(isTwoD,1),...
              'length',num2cell(idAndDimensions(isTwoD,2),...
              'width',num2cell(idAndDimensions(isTwoD,3));

%// assign threeD struct

%// clean up - we need only the two structs 
%// I use keep from the File Exchange instead of clearvars
clearvars -except twoD threeD
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, Jonas. Unfortnately, it is theoretically possible for the number of records to reach infinity, though the probability of larger sizes is small. There are ways around the unknown number of records by recasting the problem, but I really wanted to suss out best practice to deal with array lengths that were unknown ahead of time, and with no convenient upper limit.  I could allot extra elements in chunks, but that complicates my code. Was hoping for an approach that was more efficient in terms of coding time.

Comment: With regards to avoiding struct arrays and choosing between a handful of arrays of basic data types versus the same thing contained in a struct (see original post), I would prefer to take the hit in terms of variable name space pollution over the added coding complexity.

Comment: As for `explicitVariableNames`, I didn't find anything about that term on the web or Matlab docs, other than your use of the term in another StackExchange post.  I suppose that I can always use `myThing_mySubthing` and `myThing_myOtherSubthing` instead of `myThing.mySubthing` and `myThing.myOtherSubthing`. It's just much nicer to have explicit structure, and then have the language help enforce that structure.  However, I will keep the underscores in mind.

Comment: You mentioned `clear`, `keep`, and `classes` rather than structs.  I couldn't find keep in the documentation.  However, the variables are (in my actual context) object properties.  So I want to keep them around, not clear them.  I just wanted a more organized name space.

Comment: @user36800: I have added an example of why I don't think that growing an array by chunks instead of resizing every iteration adds much coding complexity. Regarding `explicitVariableNames`: I just meant that if you name your variables well, there won't be much pollution with stuff you don't know what it is. Finally, you probably want to have a look at object oriented programming.

Comment: Thank you for enhancing the example, Jonas. I didn't mean to imply that growing an array by chunks by itself was overly onerous.  I'm just trying to minimize code complexity because there are also other conditions that determine whether the array grows.  Without adding logic for vector memory allocation management, the logic for those other conditions show through clearly.  I'm a bit spoiled by C++'s STL from a decade ago, where containers internally deal with efficient growing.

Comment: I think I have a reasonable strategy for my situation. I have enough information amongst my other data objects that I can trawl to determine an upper limit on the size of the arrays. I will pre-allocate once, and use extra variables to keep track of how much of each vector is actually being used by real data. I will keep all of the pre-allocated space for all the iterations of my data mashing process, as the upper limits will be the same for all iterations. My vectors are actually sub-components of class properties, so they are persistent. By subcomponent, I mean I use very nested structures.

Comment: For example, cell arrays of struct arrays whose field are also arrays. I get lost trying to remember how its organized sometimes. <NEW PARA> I'm going to mark your answer as accepted because I suspect that there is no alternative to explicit memory management by the user. Hopefully, when Matlab's more efficient array-growth implementation extends to struct arrays, this will be done behind the scenes (unless they take a completely different approach, that is). Thanks again.

Comment: PS. I get what you said about storing everything in a numerical array for speed.  It's a real sacrifice, though.  The columns will not be associated with field names.  Such is the tradeoff between speed and readability, I suppose.